# Função que imprime índices de um array de forma incremental

Tags: php, javascript

Estou tentando implementar uma função que pode ser em PHP ou Js que pega os valores de um array e exiba eles, só que pulando os índices de forma incremental.

Por exemplo, tenho o seguinte array

```
numeros = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"];
```

Que deverá exibir os seguinte números 0, 2, 5, 9, 14...
Como pode perceber, ele inicia exibindo o índice de valor 0, pula um índice da posição atual e exibe o valor 2, pula dois índices da posição atual e exibe o valor 5, e assim por diante.

Nesse exemplo a saída deverá ser os valores
0, 2, 5, 9, 14, 20

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php

   $numeros = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"];
   $indice = 0;
   $incremento = 0;
   do{
    echo $numeros[$indice+$incremento]."<br/>";
    $indice++;
    $incremento += $indice;
   }while($indice+$incremento < count($numeros));
```

Explicações:
Você precisará de duas variáveis: uma para percorrer o array ($indice) e outra para incrementar os saltos ($incremento), elas devem está interligadas para que o avanço de uma influencie no avanço da outra até o fim do array, utilizei a estrutura de laço `do while`, para que a primeira interação fosse realizada.

Entendendo o loop

```
     $indice|$incremento|Posição do elemento| Número

  1ª:   0   |     0     |         0         |  "0"
  2ª:   1   |     1     |         2         |  "2"
  3ª:   2   |     3     |         5         |  "4"
  4ª:   3   |     7     |         10        |  "9"
  5ª:   4   |     11    |         15        |  "14"
  6ª:   5   |     16    |         21        |  "20"
```

E o laço é encerrado pois a soma do $indice + $incremento tem que ser menor que a quantidade de elementos do array `$indice+$incremento < count($numeros)`.

Espero ter contribuído;

Answer (score 0):

Em JavaScript:

```
function skipIndex(arr){
  let newArr = []
  for (let i = 0, jump = 2; i < arr.length; i+=jump, jump++){
    newArr.push(arr[i])
  }
  return newArr
}
```